# capitalization rules in English

Tags: capitalization

Do we capitalize the names of diseases?please give me some information about this question. Also include the reasons for capitalizing a specific disease and not capitalizing the others.

Comment: And I want a pony :) We do our best here, demanding a quick and comprehensive reply will not make the reply any more quick or comprehensive, and just makes your request sound rather rude.

Comment: I didn't mean it.you are misunderstanding me.i actually had to complete my assignment regarding this topic.that's it

Answer (score 2):

In general, disease names are not capitalized in English - words such as *diabetes*, *cholera* or *mumps* are common nouns.

The disease names that are capitalized are ones that are initialisms or acronyms (*AIDS*, *COVID-19*, etc.), or ones that derive their names from proper nouns, such as names or regions (*Ebola*, *Alzheimer('s) disease*).